# Are the Survey rankings for the National Research Council really more objective than the Regression rankings?

Tags: graduate-school

[This blog post](http://scienceblogs.com/catdynamics/2010/09/nrc_the_rankings.php) argues so, but I have my doubts since the author works at a graduate program whose S-rankings are much better than its R-rankings. I have a feeling that R-rankings do capture some things that S-rankings don't capture. Professors who are far ahead of their time, for example, might be recognized as such, but I would expect that their papers probably won't get very high citation counts for some time.

Comment: Do you mind perhaps elaborating on what S and R rankings are here in the question. Also I assume by NRC you mean the National Research Counsel? Although I do it frequently as well, best not to leave undefined acronyms when possible.

Answer (score 6):

No, both rankings are basically [nonsense](http://chronicle.com/article/Too-Big-to-Fail/127212/).  Even if you agree with the NRC's choice of a single "quality" model across all intellectual disciplines, the rankings are based on horrendously incomplete and incorrect data.  This is especially true in [computer](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=466) [science](http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2011/12/142542-doctoral-program-rankings-for-us-computing-programs/fulltext).

Also, the claim in the blog post is an obvious joke.  The S-rankings are "better" because  writer's home department's S-ranking was better than its R-ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Any ranking that tries to distill a large bunch of heterogeneous statistics into a single number should be treated with a healthy dose of skepticism. There is no inherent reason why a particular set of statistics should be weighted with one set of weights instead of another—and the two different weights could lead to widely divergent results.

That said, if you see a large number of rankings, and they all tend to have fairly similar results, there can be some predictive power in the *collective* set of rankings. And I would say it's a "loose" scheme at best: the difference between #1 and #2 on such lists is probably not indicative of much; the difference between #10 and #30 or #50 is much more meaningful.